# Spring Boot - Creating HTTPS-connection does not work

Tags: java, web-applications, https, spring-boot

I'm using **Spring Boot Framework** to develop a web application with **embedded** **Tomcat**. Need get some https connection for multiple ports.

For this I used **SpringApplicationBuilder**, like this here:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder
            = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

    parentBuilder.child(WithoutClientAuth.class)
            .properties("server.port:8443")
            .properties("security.require_ssl=true")
            .properties("ssl.key-store=server.jks")
            .properties("ssl.key-store-password=password")
            .properties("ssl.key-password=password")
            .run(args);

    parentBuilder.child(WithClientAuth.class)
            .properties("server.port:9443")
            .properties("security.require_ssl=true")
            .properties("ssl.key-store=server.jks")
            .properties("ssl.key-store-password=password")
            .properties("ssl.key-password=password")
            .run(args);
```

But, after starting the application, the communication protocol is not secure. Able to see that in Output:

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s):  9443 (http)
StandardService                : Starting service Tomcat
StandardEngine                 : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
```

Do you have a idea to get a secure communication in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The properties that you have used for the SSL configuration are wrong. They should all be prefixed with `server.`:

```
parentBuilder.child(WithoutClientAuth.class)
        .properties("server.port:8443")
        .properties("security.require_ssl=true")
        .properties("server.ssl.key-store=server.jks")
        .properties("server.ssl.key-store-password=password")
        .properties("server.ssl.key-password=password")
        .run(args);
```